# Typo3 logout doesn't work

Tags: php, session, typo3-6.2.x

I'm using Typo3 v.6.2.19 on website which was build by third party and I'm now maintaining. The sytem was upgraded from Typo3 v.6.1.7 to 6.2.19 and now I'm experiencing an issue with the logout form:

1. Open the site and login.
2. See the homepage which shows the user-specific block, homepage is only available for logged in users (that is an intranet-site)
3. Open a new browser tab and open the logout page with a logout form.
4. Submit the logout form.
5. Reload the tab with homepage - still can see the page and user-specific block, means user session still appears to be logged in.

Yes the site is highly customized, but felogin core extension seem to be not customized.

The logout form looks like this

```
<form action="nc/logout.html" target="_top" method="post" class="se_forms form_felogout">
    <button class="se_forms_submit" type="submit" name="submit">To homepage</button>

    <div class="felogin-hidden">
        <input type="hidden" name="logintype" value="logout">
        <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="1515">
        <input type="hidden" name="tx_felogin_pi1[noredirect]" value="0">
    </div>
</form>
```

the page with id `1515` is a folder which contains all the user data.

I think any sort of advice will help, cause googling doesn't show any relevant topics. I've already stepped through the custom code which deals with login process - it seem to not interfere with logout process itself, also checked the cookie handling and fixed the cookie domain setting. I know the question is vague and it is hard to post any specific code here since system is huge. Therefore I'd love to hear at least a list of suggestions what to check in Typo3 behavior or settings maybe.

Comment: Can you logout successful within the "main" tab?

Comment: Well, the logout request is handled without errors, but both browser tabs will show logged in page as long as I try to load it again.